# Implementing some logic during the application startup itself in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to create a Spring MVC application. While starting the application in server itself I need some to implement some excel file reading logic. I am new to Spring. Can I use interceptors for this? Once the excel is read it will be saved in a map and that map will be used for the rest of the things.

Comment: What version of Spring?  What version of Java?  Add as many more specifics about what you are trying to achieve as possible.  What have you tried already?

Comment: A simple way would be to use an init-method on a singleton bean: Spring ensures it runs at startup before any multithread request processing.

Comment: I am using Spring MVC 3 with Java 1.6. My application will have some static input files (.xls). I have to read them and store the datas in a map during server startup itself and show the datas in the home page to user.

Comment: if you are using spring boot which I highly recommend see this link https://spring.io/blog/2015/09/01/react-js-and-spring-data-rest-part-1-basic-features and `CommandLineRunner`

Answer (score 0):

Use a PostConstruct method to achieve the desired requirement. This will be called when all the dependencies are injected and when container is brought up.

```
@PostConstruct
    public void loadData(){
        // Read from your excel file here.
    }
```

Comment: Thanks minion. Where I have to add this method? In my controller class?

Comment: Create a bean with @component to load it.